# Get Particular node value in array from xml

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, xml, xmlhttprequest

I have one variable name as result in javascript Function.

The result variable's value is xml,

[image]

I need to form an Array with the opportunityid(which is highlighted in Image) values only.

how to get from the particular node value and form a array.?

I was used following Function,

```
function guid(){
var xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>" + 
    "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">" + 
    GenerateAuthenticationHeader() +
    "<soap:Body>" + 
    "<RetrieveMultiple xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices\">" + 
    "<query xmlns:q1=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2006/Query\" xsi:type=\"q1:QueryExpression\">" + 
    "<q1:EntityName>opportunity </q1:EntityName>" + 
    "<q1:ColumnSet xsi:type='q1:ColumnSet'>" + 
    "<q1:Attributes>" + 
    "<q1:Attribute>opportunity id</q1:Attribute>" +
    "</q1:Attributes>" + 
    "</q1:ColumnSet>" + 
    "<q1:Distinct>false</q1:Distinct>" + 

    "</query></RetrieveMultiple>" +
    "</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";


    var xmlHttpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");

    xmlHttpRequest.Open("POST", "/mscrmservices/2007/CrmService.asmx", false);
    xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices/RetrieveMultiple");
    xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", xml.length);
    xmlHttpRequest.send(xml);

    var result = xmlHttpRequest.responseXML.xml;
    var doc = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument");
    doc.async = false;
    doc.loadXML(result);

}
```

Comment: Does that happen in the client side? Have you tried to parse the xml as an javascript object and then just iterate over the  right object components? If that is your case you could use lodash to crawl it or you could build your own crawler.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see the structure of your xml, it is as follows:

```
<soap:Body>
    <RetrieveMultipleResponse>
      <RetrieveMultipleResult>
        <BusinessEntities>
          <BusinessEntity>
            <q1:oppourtunityid>
            </q1:oppourtunityid>
          </BusinessEntity>
        </BusinessEntities>
      </RetrieveMultipleResult>
   </RetrieveMultipleResponse>
 </soap:Body>
```

for this you can make use of DOM Element as follows:

```
var businessEntites = result.getElementsByTagName('BusinessEntity');
var oppidArr = [];
for(var i=0; i<businessEntities.length; i++)
{
   var oppid = businessEntites.item(i).getElementsByTagName('q1:oppourtunityid').item(0).childNodes[0].nodeValue;
   oppidArr[i] = oppid;
}
```

Comment: object doesn't support or method error will come when i implent the javascript function

Comment: please gothrough my question again.I added the javascript for getting the xml.I just use var businessEntites = result.getElementsByTagName('BusinessEntity'); in my code .It shows Object dosen't support or method error

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you should try below code, I have copied some of it from Mozilla's site as it's having best practice code with conditions :)

```
function guid(){
    var xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>" + 
        "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">" + 
        GenerateAuthenticationHeader() +
        "<soap:Body>" + 
        "<RetrieveMultiple xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices\">" + 
        "<query xmlns:q1=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2006/Query\" xsi:type=\"q1:QueryExpression\">" + 
        "<q1:EntityName>opportunity </q1:EntityName>" + 
        "<q1:ColumnSet xsi:type='q1:ColumnSet'>" + 
        "<q1:Attributes>" + 
        "<q1:Attribute>opportunity id</q1:Attribute>" +
        "</q1:Attributes>" + 
        "</q1:ColumnSet>" + 
        "<q1:Distinct>false</q1:Distinct>" + 

        "</query></RetrieveMultiple>" +
        "</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";


    var xmlHttpRequest;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
        xmlHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
        try {
            xmlHttpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } 
        catch (e) {
            try {
                xmlHttpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } 
            catch (e) {}
        }
    }

    if (!xmlHttpRequest) {
        alert('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
        return false;
    }

    xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = getContents;
    xmlHttpRequest.open("POST", "/mscrmservices/2007/CrmService.asmx", false);
    xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices/RetrieveMultiple");
    xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", xml.length);
    xmlHttpRequest.send(xml);

    function getContents() {
        if (xmlHttpRequest.readyState === 4) {
            if (xmlHttpRequest.status === 200) {
                var xmldoc = xmlHttpRequest.responseXML;
                var root_node = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('q1:Attributes').item(0);
                alert(root_node.firstChild.data);
            } else {
                alert('There was a problem with the request.');
            }
        }
    }
}
```